Tv show set in a near future law firm. Lots of ethical problems caused by technology were considered
I watched this on TV in the uk in the 00s. It was made and set in America.It was set in a law firm maybe ten or twenty years in the future.
There was only ever one season it was not renewed.
Most of the episodes considered the ethical problems concerned with the use of fictional new technology.
There was one where members of boyband in their 70s were taking a treatment to look in their 20s and trying to force a dissenting band member to also take the treatment.
There was a teenager trying to stop their parents constantly monitoring them.
One of the lawyers was obsessed, infatuated with his holographic 'secretary.'There was a episode about designer babies. There was one about human clones.
There was one where a man with learning difficulties took experimental medicine that increased his intelligence, but they then found out it also risked killing him.

Century City (I watched this in the early 2000s, too)

Century City is an American science fiction-legal drama television
series created by Ed Zuckerman, that aired on CBS from March 16, 2004,
to January 20, 2005, before being cancelled due to low ratings. The
series is set in Los Angeles in the year 2030.

Tvtropes has more details

Made in 2004, featuring LA of 2030. Bright, clean, with emerging
technologies like cybernetic enhancement and genetic engineering much
more prevalent, with the law firm on the show handling cases related
to this. Overall it looked pretty believable.


There was one where members of boyband in their 70s were taking a treatment to look in their 20s and trying to force a dissenting band member to also take the treatment.

Older Than They Look: Comes up twice, first with the 70-year old boy
band from the eighties, fresh out of plastic surgery and ready to go
on the road, and the second time with the child star that wants to
take hormone suppressants to hold onto his sitcom stardom (and get a
second chance at childhood).

Complete episode list:
There was one where a man with learning difficulties took experimental medicine that increased his intelligence, but they then found out it also risked killing him.

S1.E4 ∙ A Mind Is a Terrible Thing to Lose Tue, Mar 30, 2004 The firm
deals with a case where a mentally dysfunctional man is cured by a
process that may ultimately kill him

